# Scroll to certain position for 'single' pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In my WordPress site, on single pages, I'd like the scroll bar to automatically scroll to a certain position (say, 400px from the top). The reason is because I have a video player under the header that shows on every page. When the user clicks on a post from the home page, I want the post to come up in the single page without the user having to scroll down. I'm guessing I can use the scroll.to function but am unsure how to go about it. Does anyone have an idea how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to actually 'slide' down the page. You could just use anchors to link to a page, and a point on that page:

http://www.webmasterslibrary.com/articles/readArticle.jsp?cid=anchors